# Can I use Tracker to catalog my ebook library?

Tags: laptop, tablet

Let me start by explaining that I am not technologically adept, so I would be very grateful if you could answer my question with that in mind.

I have a Kindle ebook library of close to 6,000 books in the Amazon cloud. I was using an app called Book Collections Plus as the catalog on a Fire HD. The HD died, and with it, my entire catalog disappeared. I have learned that putting the app on my new Fire is useless because Amazon keeps changing the file extensions on the file names and even changes where the files are stored on the device, so that the app cannot find the files.

These are my questions:

Could Tracker be downloaded and work efficiently on a Fire tablet with an expanded memory?

If Tracker won't work on a Fire, then I have a PC laptop with Windows 10. I would, though, prefer to have the catalog on the Fire.

Would I be able to catalog books according to my own system?  And list individual books in multiple categories?  Is there a limit to the number of categories, sub-categories and sub-sub-categories I could create?

Do I understand the following correctly?  I would have to download the entire library onto the device (Fire or Laptop). If I have to download Tracker onto my laptop, I could limit its activity to a particular directory, or even particular types of files (specifically Amazon file extensions). I would need to edit the metadata on every single book individually. No matter how Amazon changes file extensions or where Amazon stores the files (on the Fire), I would always be able to find it and catalog it.

Thank you very much for your time and attention.

With regard,

Katherine Sotol

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple different models of the Kindle Fire HD, so without knowing the specific model of your Kindle Fire HD I can't provide information on how to install Ubuntu on it if that is what you are trying to do, however for starters visit the [Ubuntu Touch Kindle Fire HD 8.9" wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices/jem). Visit all of the links on the wiki and review all of the instructions before doing anything, as the Ubuntu Touch installation requires wiping your system and factory reset. Before wiping your system, you should also make a complete backup of your Kindle Fire for recovery purposes.

I don't know if you are comfortable with wiping your system and *I wouldn't do it if it was my device*, so I will also suggest an easier way of cataloging your ebook library. If you don't mind copying your ebook library to your laptop, Calibre ebook reader from the Ubuntu Software Center can manage all your cataloging tasks automatically by using the existing metadata of the ebooks in your Calibre library. Changes in the way an ebook is catalogued can be easily done by editing the ebook's metadata in Calibre.  Calibre can also be installed in Windows.

Calibre is meant to be a complete ebook library solution. It includes library management, format conversion, news feeds to ebook conversion as well as ebook reader sync features.

Calibre is primarily an ebook cataloging program. It manages your ebook
collection for you. It is designed around the concept of the logical book,
i.e. a single entry in the database that may correspond to ebooks in several formats.

Calibre has a modular device driver design that makes adding support for different ebook reader devices easy. Syncing supports updating metadata on the device from metadata in the library and the creation of collections on the device based on the tags defined in the library view.